# Typescript problem with useFieldArray with property name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form

I have the following typescript problem with useFieldArray. It does not recognize at the controller under name that: `name={test.${index}.firstname}`

`That's where the error comes: controller.d.ts(18, 5): The expected type comes from property 'name' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { render: ({ field, fieldState, formState, }: { field: ControllerRenderProps<Record<string, any>, ${string}|${string}.${string}|${string}.${number}>; fieldState: ControllerFieldState; formState: FormState<...>; }) => ReactElement<...>; } & UseControllerProps<...>'`

Then under defaultValue neither item.name nor item.value goes these subitems do not exist under item.

How can I solve this problem?

My code: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-frost-lpnwe?file=/src/components/BasicData.tsx

Comment: I saw your code sand box has not problem

Comment: But of course there is a problem. Look by name. When you put a index in the string, than you see the problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-goldberg-tpgl6

Comment: What is that you want to do exactly? Why do you need a field array here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution from the official document.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/

**In the Typescript section:**

> for nested field array, you will have to cast the field array by its name.

```js
const { fields } = useFieldArray({ name: `test.${index}.keyValue` as 'test.0.keyValue' });
```

---

So for your case, the name should be

```js
name={`test.${index}.firstname` as `test.0.firstname`}
```

Here is [the codesandbox for demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-river-ecm3w?file=/src/components/BasicData.tsx:821-875)