# Dynamic input as array of strings using Zod and React Hook Form

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form, zod

On my screen I will can receive `emails: string[]`. And it will be rendered with the amount of the length of this array `{emailsFields.map((field, index) => {...}` but using the [Zod](https://zod.dev/) I have a validation service that you can see below.

```
export const emails = validationService
  .string({
    required_error: 'Email is required'
  })
  .email('Must be a valid email')
  .array()
```

Using this `emails` variable as the `name` at my Input component `name='emails'` I use to be controlled. It can be rendered the all emails that I received as the image below.

```
<TextFieldWithPlusIcon
   key={field.id}
   name="emails"
   label="Corporate email"
   placeholder="name@email.com"
   keyboardType="email-address"
   autoCapitalize="none"
   defaultValue={defaultValues.emails[index]}
   autoCorrect={false}
/>
```

[image: Two inputs with different emails that was rendered.]

And when I type in one of these inputs, everyone with emails is changed like the other image below.

[image: Two inputs with the same emails because was typed in an input and changed the other.]

I found some topics here on Stackoverflow that they say to use like a index in the `name` property like this `name={'[${field.id}].emails'}` and it works but the emails that I receive at my component for an example if I receive a array with two strings, two inputs are rendered but without the received values inserted at in the input component. Again like the image below

[image: Two inputs rendered but without the values]

I tried and it worked but the values in the component aren't rendered.

[React-Hook Form with useFieldArray: TextField value does not show up in the console. How can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088488/react-hook-form-with-usefieldarray-textfield-value-does-not-show-up-in-the-cons)

[Typescript problem with useFieldArray with property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68427801/typescript-problem-with-usefieldarray-with-property-name)

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to this problem? I am trying to do something similar

Comment: @RobertHinckley The react hook form they have functions to do that.

Comment: @VagnerWentz can you tell us the function?